# The Last Monday

Tags: code-golf, date

Monday, October 31st, is Halloween. And it got me thinking -- I wonder what other months have the last day of the month *also* be a Monday?

#### Input

- A positive integer [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963) representing a year, `10000 > y > 0`.
- The input can be padded with zeros (e.g., `0025` for year `25`) if
  required.

#### Output

- A list of the months of that year where the last day of the month is a Monday.
- This can be as month names (e.g., `January, March, October`), or shortnames (`Jan, Mar, Oct`), or numbers (`1, 3, 10`), as separate lines or a list or delimited, etc., just so long as it's unambiguous to the reader.
- The output format must be consistent:

  - For all years input (meaning, you can't output month names for some inputs, and month numbers for other inputs)
  - As well as consistent per output (meaning, you can't output `1` for `January` in the same output as `Jul` for `July`)
  - Basically, pick one format and stick to it.

#### Rules

- Assume the Gregorian calendar for input/output, even down to `y = 1`.
- Leap years must be properly accounted for (as a reminder: every year divisible by 4, except not years divisible by 100, unless also divisible by 400 -- 1700, 1800, 1900 all weren't leap years, but 2000 was).
- You may use any built-ins or other date calculation tools you like.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

#### Examples

```
   1 --> Apr, Dec
 297 --> May
1776 --> Sep
2000 --> Jan, Jul
2016 --> Feb, Oct
3385 --> Jan, Feb, Oct
```

---

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=97585,OVERRIDE_USER=42963;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [Related 1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69510/42963) and [Related 2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42402/42963).

Comment: Related but not duplicates or?

Comment: @ElPedro Related but not duplicates. The first does not allow any built-ins and asks for a fixed date/day combo (Friday the 13th), while the second asks for the last Sunday of every month of the year, limited between 1900 to 3015.

Comment: Sorry @TimmD. My misunderstanding of your comment.

Comment: @ElPedro No problem! I would rather have a question and have it be clear, than to *not* have a question and have something unclear.

Comment: Can we print the months as YearMonth, for instance `2016-02 2016-10`?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Sure, that's fine, so long as it's consistent.

Comment: Can we return an array with falsy values in place of non-Monday months (e.g. `[0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0]`)? There's a JS ES6 answer that currently does this.

Comment: @ETHproductions Yeah, that's fine, since it's still unambiguous to the reader. The output formatting isn't the interesting part of this challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM) with [dfns](http://dfns.dyalog.com/)'s [cal](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_cal.htm), Version 15.0: 22; Version 16.0: 19 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

The cal function comes with a default install, just enter `)copy dfns`.

#### Version 15.0: `∊⎕{⍵/⍨2=≢⍎⊢⌿cal⍺⍵}¨⍳12`

`∊` enlist (flatten)

`⎕{`...`}¨` numeric input as left argument to the following anonymous function, taking each of the right side values as right argument in turn

`⍵/⍨` the argument if (gives an empty list if not)

`2=` two (namely Sunday and Monday) is equal to

`≢` the tally of

`⍎` the numbers in

`⊢⌿` the bottom-most row of

`cal` the calendar for

`⍺⍵` year left-argument, month right-argument, the latter being

`⍳12` 1 to 12

#### Version 16.0: `⍸2=⎕{≢⍎⊢⌿cal⍺⍵}¨⍳12`

`⍸` the indices where

`2=` two equals (namely Sunday and Monday)

`⎕{`...`}¨` numeric input as left argument to the following anonymous function, taking each of the right side values as right argument in turn

`≢` the tally of

`⍎` the numbers in

`⊢⌿` the bottom-most row of

`cal` the calendar for

`⍺⍵` year left-argument, month right-argument, the latter being

`⍳12` 1 to 12

Answer (score 18):

## JavaScript (Firefox 30+), <s>112</s> <s>109</s> <s>103</s> 95 bytes

Look ma, no built-ins!

```
y=>[for(m of(i=0,y%4|y%400*!(y%100)&&6)+"63153042641")if((i++,y+(y>>2)-(y/100|0)*3/4|0)%7==m)i]
```

Here's a 107-byte ES6 version:

```
y=>[...(y%4|y%400*!(y%100)&&6)+"63153042641"].map((m,i)=>(y+(y>>2)-(y/100|0)*3/4|0)%7-m?0:i+1).filter(x=>x)
```

And here's my previous attempt, <s>123</s> 113 bytes of ES6:

```
y=>[(l=y%4|y%400*!(y%100))?[7]:[1,7],[4,12],[9],[3,6],[8,11],[5],l?[1,2,10]:[2,10]][(y+(y>>2)-(y/100|0)*3/4|0)%7]
```

### Explanation

The day of the week of a particular year is calculated like so:

```
y+(y>>2)-(y/100|0)*3/4|0)%7
```

In other words:

- Take `y`.
- Add the number of 4th years before `y` (`y>>2`).
- Subtract the number of 100th years before `y` (`y/100|0`).
- Add back in the number of 400th years before `y`; this is 1/4 of `y/100|0`, so we use `*3/4|0`.

Then we modulo the result by 7. If we let `0` mean Sunday, `1` mean Monday, etc., the result corresponds to the day of the week of December 31st of that year. Therefore, for December, we want to check if the result is `1`. This gives us the last char in the string.

The last day of November is 31 days before the last day of December. This means that for the last day of November to be a Monday, Dec 31 needs to be a `(1 + 31) % 7 = 4` = Thursday.

This procedure is repeated until we get back to March (a `3`). Whether or not there is a leap day, the last day of February is 31 days before the last day of March, so we can calculate that too (it's `(3 + 31) % 7 = 6`). The tricky part is finding the correct value for January:

- If it is a leap year, the last day of January is 29 days before the last day of Feb, resulting in `(6 + 29) % 7 = 0`.
- Otherwise, it is 28 days before the last day of Feb, resulting in `(6 + 28) % 7 = 6`.

We can calculate whether or not it is a leap year with the following snippet:

```
!(y%400)|y%100*!(y%4)
```

This gives `0` if `y` is not a leap year, and a positive integer otherwise. This leads us to

```
!(y%400)|y%100*!(y%4)?0:6
```

for calculating the day for January. However, we can do better by reversing the conditions:

```
y%4|y%400*!(y%100)?6:0
```

Since the falsy result is always 0 anyway, we can reduce it to

```
y%4|y%400*!(y%100)&&6
```

saving one more precious byte.

Putting it all together, we loop through each char in the string, checking if each is equal to the day of the week of Dec 31st. We keep the indexes of the ones that match, returning this array in the end. And that is how you do leap year calculations without built-ins.

Comment: Owww... My brain, did you account for leap years in alla that?

Comment: @carusocomputing That's what `!(y%4)*y%100|!(y%400)` is for. *every year divisible by 4, except not years divisible by 100, unless also divisible by 400*

Comment: Hopefully `y+(y>>2)+(z=y/25>>2)+(z>>2)` still saves you a byte.

Comment: @Neil Thanks, but I found a better way :-)

Comment: Nice; I saved 6 bytes on my Batch port using `(y*5/4-(y/100)*3/4)`.

Comment: Make that 8 bytes - `(y*5/4-y/100*3/4)`.

Comment: @Neil I was just going to ask if you could remove those parens ;-)

Comment: This is just magnificent! :)

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), <s>67</s> <s>65</s> <s>64</s> <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```
y=>[for(_ of(m='')+1e11)if(new Date(y+400,++m).getDay()==2)m]
```

Saved <s>2</s> <s>4</s> 6 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions. <s>Saved another byte by outputting the months in reverse order.</s>

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes by winging it without `.keys()`: `y=>[for(_ of(m=0,Array(12)))if(new Date(y+400,++m).getDay()==2)m]`

Comment: @ETHproductions I can save a further byte by reversing the order!

Comment: Reverse order is fine. Formatting the output isn't the interesting part of this challenge.

Comment: What's our policy on Array Comprehensions now that they've been removed from the spec?

Comment: You can save another 2 bytes by skipping `Array(12)` altogether:  `y=>[for(_ of(m=0,1e11+""))if(new Date(y+400,++m).getDay()==2)m]`

Comment: @MayorMonty I believe the policy is that since they still work in Firefox 30+, they are still a valid feature.

Comment: BTW, I count 64 bytes in your current solution. (My suggestion is 63)

Comment: @ETHproductions Ah, all my byte counts are off by 1 for some reason. I'll fix that later.

Comment: Switch it around to save the parens: `for(_ of(m="")+1e11)`

Comment: @ETHproductions Bah, why didn't you just say so in the first place...

Comment: @Neil I hadn't thought of using `1e11+(m="")` ;)

Answer (score 9):

## MySQL, <s>183</s> <s>134</s> <s>129</s> 106 bytes

```
SET @y=2016;SELECT help_topic_id AS m FROM mysql.help_topic HAVING m BETWEEN 1 AND 12 AND 2=DAYOFWEEK(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(@y,-m,-1)))
```

Replace `2016` with the desired year. Run.

Rev. 2: Used the `help_topics` table in the default installation instead of creating a temporary table.

Rev.3: Adopted [aross´s `-` trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97697#97697) and noticed I can also omit the quotes for `"-1"`.
However, `-1` is required in MySQL: I need a full date.

Rev.4: Restriction `m BETWEEN 1 AND 12` could be done as `m>0 AND m<13` (-6), but is not needed at all - invalid values will be ignored; warnings will be counted but not listed.

Comment: You need really the table shema mysql? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqlhelp_topic-table/

Comment: @JörgHülsermann I don´t get your point.

Comment: Should `FROM help_topic` without `mysql.` work? I have try it not

Comment: @JörgHülsermann only if you prepend `USE mysql;` The correct database must be selected somehow.

Comment: will this work for year 999 and earlier ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk From the MySQL manual: `The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'. ` I would add that to the description; but I am reluctant to edit a four year old post.

Comment: oh, I missed that part about being 4 years old. I fully understand.

Answer (score 5):

### Batch, <s>160</s> 152 bytes

```
@set/ay=%1,m=0,j=6*!(!(y%%4)*(y%%100)+(y%%400)),y=(y*5/4-y/100*3/4)%%7
@for %%d in (%j% 6 3 1 5 3 0 4 2 6 4 1)do @set/am+=1&if %%d==%y% call echo %%m%%
```

Port of @ETHproduction's answer. With month abbreviations for <s>197</s> 189 bytes:

```
@set/ay=%1,j=6*!(!(y%%4)*(y%%100)+(y%%400)),y=(y*5/4-y/100*3/4)%%7
@for %%m in (Jan.%j% Feb.6 Mar.3 Apr.1 May.5 Jun.3 Jul.0 Aug.4 Sep.2 Oct.6 Nov.4 Dec.1)do @if %%~xm==.%y% call echo %%~nm
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl+cal, 46 bytes

```
say`cal $_ $ARGV[0]`=~/\n.{5}\n/&&$_ for 1..12
```

Example:

```
$ perl -E 'say`cal $_ $ARGV[0]`=~/\n.{5}\n/&&$_ for 1..12' 2016

2







10


$
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is perl + cal, not just perl :-p. For example, my Windows machine has perl, but this won't work there.

Comment: Fair point, updated this and my bash attempt.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 64 bytes

Includes +1 for `-n`

Give input on STDIN:

```
perl -M5.010 mon.pl <<< 2016
```

`mon.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
map$b.=$/.gmtime$_.e4,-7e6..3e7;say$b=~/on (\S+ )\S.* $_.* 1 /g
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>62</s> 57 bytes

```
DayName@DayRange[{#},{#+1},"EndOfMonth"]~Position~Monday&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input and returns a list of single-element lists of numbers as output. I'm honestly not sure myself how it works anymore.

Answer (score 4):

## J, <s>48</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
[:I.(2=7|_2#@".@,@{.])&>@calendar
```

Saved 15 bytes with help from @[Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m).

Uses the calendar builtin to generate an array of strings representing the months, then parses each string to determine the whether the last Monday is the last day of the month. It outputs each month as the month number of each. That is, `Jan = 0`, `Feb = 1`, ..., `Dec = 11`.

The output of `calendar` is

```
   _3 ]\ calendar 2016
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│         Jan         │         Feb         │         Mar         │
│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│
│                 1  2│     1  2  3  4  5  6│        1  2  3  4  5│
│  3  4  5  6  7  8  9│  7  8  9 10 11 12 13│  6  7  8  9 10 11 12│
│ 10 11 12 13 14 15 16│ 14 15 16 17 18 19 20│ 13 14 15 16 17 18 19│
│ 17 18 19 20 21 22 23│ 21 22 23 24 25 26 27│ 20 21 22 23 24 25 26│
│ 24 25 26 27 28 29 30│ 28 29               │ 27 28 29 30 31      │
│ 31                  │                     │                     │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│         Apr         │         May         │         Jun         │
│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│
│                 1  2│  1  2  3  4  5  6  7│           1  2  3  4│
│  3  4  5  6  7  8  9│  8  9 10 11 12 13 14│  5  6  7  8  9 10 11│
│ 10 11 12 13 14 15 16│ 15 16 17 18 19 20 21│ 12 13 14 15 16 17 18│
│ 17 18 19 20 21 22 23│ 22 23 24 25 26 27 28│ 19 20 21 22 23 24 25│
│ 24 25 26 27 28 29 30│ 29 30 31            │ 26 27 28 29 30      │
│                     │                     │                     │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│         Jul         │         Aug         │         Sep         │
│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│
│                 1  2│     1  2  3  4  5  6│              1  2  3│
│  3  4  5  6  7  8  9│  7  8  9 10 11 12 13│  4  5  6  7  8  9 10│
│ 10 11 12 13 14 15 16│ 14 15 16 17 18 19 20│ 11 12 13 14 15 16 17│
│ 17 18 19 20 21 22 23│ 21 22 23 24 25 26 27│ 18 19 20 21 22 23 24│
│ 24 25 26 27 28 29 30│ 28 29 30 31         │ 25 26 27 28 29 30   │
│ 31                  │                     │                     │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│         Oct         │         Nov         │         Dec         │
│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│ Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa│
│                    1│        1  2  3  4  5│              1  2  3│
│  2  3  4  5  6  7  8│  6  7  8  9 10 11 12│  4  5  6  7  8  9 10│
│  9 10 11 12 13 14 15│ 13 14 15 16 17 18 19│ 11 12 13 14 15 16 17│
│ 16 17 18 19 20 21 22│ 20 21 22 23 24 25 26│ 18 19 20 21 22 23 24│
│ 23 24 25 26 27 28 29│ 27 28 29 30         │ 25 26 27 28 29 30 31│
│ 30 31               │                     │                     │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

### Usage

```
   f =: [:I.(2=7|_2#@".@,@{.])&>@calendar
   f 1
3 11
   f 297
4
   f 1776
8
   f 2000
0 6
   f 2016
1 9
   f 3385
0 1 9
```

### Explanation

```
[:I.(2=7|_2#@".@,@{.])&>@calendar  Input: year Y
                         calendar  Get 12 boxes each containing a month
    (                )&>@          Operate on each box
                    ]                Identity, get the box
         _2       {.                 Take the last two strings
                ,@                   Flatten it
             ".@                     Parse it into an array of integers
           #@                        Get the length
       7|                            Take it modulo 7
     2=                              Test if it equals 2 - it will either
                                     have two days or 9 days in the last
                                     two lines if the end is on a Monday
[:I.                               Return the indices containing a true value
```

Comment: wait, does calendar actually output ascii art?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon To be exact, the output format of `calendar` is an array of 12 boxes where each box contains a 2d array of characters

Comment: I don't even know how to do "each" in J, but this is already much shorter: `I.7=;#&.>".&.>,&.>_2{.&.>calendar 2016` If you combine all the "under-open"s you should be able to get it pretty short.

Comment: @Adám Thanks, it uses a better method but it's not a verb in J. I think it will still help though

Comment: My intention was only to inspire. I know it isn't a verb.

Comment: @Adám Inspire you did :) I saved 14 bytes with that shorter logic

Comment: Can you not replace `##\` with `I.`?

Answer (score 4):

## Java 7 ,<del>186 182</del> 172   bytes

*Thanks to kevin for saving 4 bytes*
*Thanks to @cliffroot for saving 10 bytes*

```java
int[]f(int n){int c=n-1,x=c*365+c/4+c/400-c/100,k=0,b[]={3,(n%4<1&n%100>0)|n%400<1?1:0,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3},a[]=new int[12];for(int i:b)a[k++]=(x+=i+28)%7==1?1:0;return a;}
```

## ungolfed

```java
int[] f(int n) {
 int c=n-1,x=c*365+(c/4)+(c/400)-(c/100),k=0,
   b[] = {3,(n % 4 < 1 & n % 100 > 0) | n % 400 < 1 ? 1 : 0
                                     ,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3},a = new int[ 12 ];

 if ( (n % 4 < 1 & n % 100 > 1) | n % 400 < 1 )
     b[ 1 ] = -1;
 for (int i : b)
    a[ k++ ] = (x += i + 28) % 7 == 1 ? 1 : 0;

return a;
     }
```

This version is provide by [@cliffroot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53197/cliffroot)(**168 bytes**)

```java
 static int[] f(int n) {
 int b = 13561787 | ( (n%4 < 1 & n%100 > 0) | n%400 < 1 ? 1 << 20 : 0 ),
           x = --n*365 + n/4 + n/400 - n/100,a[]=new int[12],k=0;
    while (k < 12)
    a[k++] = (x += (b >> 24 - k*2&3 ) + 28) % 7 == 1 ? 1 : 0;
  return a;   }
    }
```

## output sample

```java
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0(for input 3385)
```

Comment: After I wrote my answer I knew calculating everything yourself would be shorter.. :) Btw, you can golf `n%4==0` to `n%4<1`; `n%400==0` to `n%400<1` and `int c=...;int[]b=...,a=...` to `int c=...,b[]=...,a[]=...`.

Comment: `b` and `a` can be defined in the `int` part like this: `int ... ,b[]=...,a[]=...`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You're 2 minutes too late. ;) @Numberknot and you can also change `n%100!=0` to `n%100>0`.

Comment: Done @KevinCruijssen.

Comment: `int[]f(int n){int x=--n*365+n/4+n/400-n++/100,k=0,b[]={1,(n%4<1&n%100>0)|n%400<1?-1:-2,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1},a[]=new int[12];for(int i:b)a[k++]=(x+=i+30)%7==1?1:0;return a;}` few bytes saved

Comment: can also change `b` to `b[]={3,(n%4<1&n%100>0)|n%400<1?1:0,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3}` and `i+30` to `i+28` for 2 more bytes

Comment: and another 3 bytes `int[]f(int n){int b=13561787|((n%4<1&n%100>0)|n%400<1?1<<20:0),x=--n*365+n/4+n/400-n/100,a[]=new int[12],k=0;while(k<12)a[k++]=(x+=(b>>24-k*2&3)+28)%7==1?1:0;return a;}`

Answer (score 4):

## C, 119 bytes

```c
t=1248700335,m;main(y){for(scanf("%d",&y),t+=y&3||y%25<1&&y&15;m++,(6+y+y/4-y/100+y/400+t)%7||printf("%d,",m),t;t/=7);}
```

This uses a table that contains the offset of the weekdays of the last day of every month for a leap year, encoded in a signed 32-bit word using base 7. If it is not a leap year we add 1 to the offset of January (as you can see `y&3||y%25<1&&y&15` is used to check for years without leap days). Then we simply loop through every month and check if its last day is a Monday. Quite simple actually, no ugly hacks or tricks. Here it is slightly ungolfed:

```c
t=1248700335,m;
main(y){
  for(
    scanf("%d",&y),t+=y&3||y%25<1&&y&15;
    m++,(6+y+y/4-y/100+y/400+t)%7||printf("%d,",m),t;
    t/=7
  );
}
```

I might revisit this to rewrite it as a function to save a few characters. The `printf` also takes up a little too much space...

Comment: The printf("%d, ", m) would print something as 1, or 2, 3, so there is always one ',' more... I prefer use only spaces

Comment: Indeed, I also prefer spaces in the output actually, but I usually write my golfed C solutions so that they don't need any whitespace, so I can just nuke all whitespace from my half-golfed version when I want to check my character count.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 122 bytes

Ugh. Math with dates isn't as simple as I'd like.

```python
from datetime import*
lambda y:[m+1for m in range(12)if(date(y,12,31)if m>10else(date(y,m+2,1)-timedelta(1))).weekday()<1]
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/EHKa)

**Same length:**

```python
from datetime import*
lambda y:[m-1for m in range(2,14)if(date(y,12,31)if m>12else(date(y,m,1)-timedelta(1))).weekday()<1]
```

Comment: I wasn't even going to try Python with this one. Nice effort.

Comment: You have to include the import statement in your bytecount.

Comment: @pppery Way to notice something in an old post. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, 109 <strike>180</strike> <strike>159</strike> bytes

```
for($z=$argv[1];$m++<12;)if(date(N,strtotime(sprintf("%04d-$m-",$z).cal_days_in_month(0,$m,$z)))<2)echo"$m,";
```

- Outputs the provided year, not all of them (... always read the question)
- Ignored notices (thanks Titus)
- Change `while` to `for` as it's now a single year (again, thanks Titus)

#### Old 2

```
$z=0;while($z++<9999){$o=[];$m=0;while($m++<12)if(date("N",strtotime(sprintf("%04d-$m-","$z").cal_days_in_month(0,$m,$z)))<2)$o[]=$m;echo count($o)>0?"$z:".implode(",",$o)."
":"";}
```

Supports all years from dot to 10000, also got rid of an undefined var warning I wasn't aware of on one PC. Yes it's longer than the old version, but it's more robust.

#### Old 1

```
while($z++<9999){$o=[];$m=0;while($m++<12)if(date("N",strtotime("$z-$m-".cal_days_in_month(0,$m,$z)))<2)$o[]=$m;echo count($o)>0?"$z:".implode(",",$o)."
":"";}
```

If running on Windows or a 32bit system there will be the dreaded 2038 bug, but on a 64bit linux system it's fine.

I did attempt to use `date("t"...` which is meant to represent the last date of the given month, but the results didn't match those previously mentioned in this thread.

Comment: -2: "$z" needs no quotes
-7: ignore the _notices_ (they not printed with default settings: do not init `$z`, no quotes for `N`)
-1: `for` instead of `while`
**-43**: take input as requested instead of looping through the years
-3: `join` instead of `implode`
-16: direct output: `for($z=$argv[1];$m++<12;)if(date(N,strtotime(sprintf("%04d-$m-",$z).cal_days_in_month(0,$m,$z)))<2)echo"$m,";`
+9 if you insist on having no trailing comma: `echo$o=$o?",$m":$m;`

Comment: Ahh misread the question! Thought it was for all years.. oops :B Thanks for the other suggestions as well, will get on them

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 21 bytes

```
12:"G@QhO6(YO9XO77=?@
```

Months are displayed as numbers.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTI6IkdAUWhPNihZTzlYTzc3PT9A&input=MjAxNg) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBYS3gKMTI6IktAUWhPNihZTzlYTzc3PT9ACl1dJmhE&input=WzEgMjk3IDE3NzYgMjAwMCAyMDE2IDMzODVd).

#### Explanation

This uses date conversion builtin functions. For the given year it tests which months' last day is Monday.

Instead of explicitly specifying the last day of month `k` (which may be 28, 29, 30 or 31), we specify the `0`-th day of month `k+1`, which is equivalent and does not depend on month or year.

```
12:      % Push [1 2 ... 12] (months)
"        % For each month k
  G      %   Push input
  @Q     %   Push k+1
  h      %   Concatenate
  O6(    %   Postpend four zeros. For example, for input 2016 and month k=1 
         %   (first iteration) this gives [2016 2 0 0 0 0] (year, month, day,
         %   hour, min, sec). The 0-th day of month k+1 is the same as the
         %   last day of month k.
  YO     %   Convert the above 6-element date vector to date number
  9XO    %   Convert date number to date string with output format 9, which 
         %   is weekday as a capital letter
  77=    %   Is it an 'M'?
  ?      %   If so
    @    %     Push current month (will be implicitly displayed)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 56 bytes

```bash
seq -f1month-1day$1-%g-1 12|date -f- +%B%u|sed -n s/1//p
```

Appears to require `date` version 8.25.  The 8.23 version in Ideone doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 537 bytes

Because – you know – Excel!

Takes input year in A1. Returns hexadecimal list of months; 1=January, C= December. Since each month is a single digit, no separator is needed.

```
=IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,1,1),0)),1,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,2,1),0)),2,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,3,1),0)),3,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,4,1),0)),4,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,5,1),0)),5,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,6,1),0)),6,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,7,1),0)),7,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,8,1),0)),8,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,9,1),0)),9,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,10,1),0)),"A","")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,11,1),0)),"B","")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,12,1),0)),"C","")
```

Example: A1 contains 2016. B1 contains the above formula, and displays as `2A`, meaning February and October.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>428</s> <s>97</s> 96 bytes

Input in A1.  Output un-separated Hexadecimal values (January = 0, December = B)

```
=IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1+2000,1,31)),0,"")&CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(A1+2000,3,0)),4,19,6,"3B",8,25,"7A")
```

Added 10 bytes ("+2000") to allow handling of pre-1990 dates.

Saved 11 bytes thanks to @[Engineer Toast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38183/engineer-toast).

---

First attempt (428 bytes), borrowing heavily from @[Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)'s solution.

```
=IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,1,31)),1,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,2,1),0)),2,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,3,31)),3,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,4,30)),4,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,5,31)),5,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,6,30)),6,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,7,31)),7,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,8,31)),8,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,9,30)),9,"")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,10,31)),"A","")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,11,30)),"B","")&IF(2=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,12,31)),"C","")
```

Comment: How does this work on years earlier than 1900? The test case `297 -> May` returns `6` with this formula. Shouldn't it be 4? `1776` gives `7A` instead of just `8` for September.

Comment: If you get it to work, though, you can probably use `Date(A1,3,0)` instead of `EOMONTH(DATE(A1,2,1),0)`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>96</s> <s>95</s> <s>76</s> <s>71</s> <s>69</s> <s>64</s> 61 bytes

Note: year numbers must be padded to 4 chars, like `0070`.

```
for(;13+$i-=1;)date(N,mktime(0,0,0,1-$i,0,$argn))-1||print$i;
```

Run like this:

```
echo 3385 | php -nR 'for(;13+$i-=1;)date(N,mktime(0,0,0,1-$i,0,$argn))-1||print$i;';echo
> -1-2-10
```

## Explanation

Iterates from -1 to -12. Create date using mktime, day `0` (the last day of the previous month) and month `2..13`. Format the date as **day number**, and if the result is 1, print the current number. The negative sign `-` is used as the delimiter.

## [The Millenium Bug Strikes Again!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)

Note that with this version, the range `0..100` is interpreted as `1970..2069`. This is no problem for the range `0..69`, as weeks have a pattern that repeats every 400 years (146097 days, exactly 20871 weeks), but for the range `70..99`, 1900 is added to the year number, which is not a multiple of 400. To fix that problem JUST for 30 year numbers in a range of 10k, the simplest way is to add 400 to the year number to prevent the 2-digit interpretation (**+4 bytes**):

```
for(;13+$i-=1;)date(N,mktime(0,0,0,1-$i,0,$argn+400))-1||print$i;
```

## Tweaks

- Saved a byte by using `!~-$i` to compare `$i` with `1` (`-1` binary negated is `0`, logically negated is `true`; every other number is `false`), so parentheses aren't needed
- Saved 19 bytes by using `last day ofYYYY-m` notation to create the date
- Saved 5 bytes by using `date` and `strtotime` instead of `date_create`
- Saved 2 bytes by counting from negative numbers, using the negative sign as output delimiter (negative month numbers don't exist) and also as delim in the `YYYY-m` part of the date
- Saved 5 bytes by using `mktime` instead of `strtotime`. Reverted to using day `0` (`mktime` also supports month 13, so `0-13`==`31-12`)
- Saved 3 bytes by using `-R` to make `$argn` available

Comment: `mktime` removes the necessity to pad the year, doesn´t it?

Comment: @Titus, sharp. Well I just figured out that `mktime` is [counter-intuitive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php#120096), because the arguments are taken as `INT`s. That means you can't pad the year... so everything in range `0..100` is interpreted as `1970..2070`. That is no problem for the range `0..70` because 400 years have an exact number of weeks (so calendars repeat the pattern every 400 years), but `70..99` adds 1900 (not a multiple of 400!). Therefore new ver. has a bug.

Comment: Only solution I see for that right now is`$argv[1]+400` ... unless Julian and Gregorian weekdays differ.

Comment: @Titus, yep. Rules say use Gregorian cal

Answer (score 3):

## C, 214 bytes

```
main(int a,char *b[]){for(int x,y,d,m=12;m;m--){y=atoi(b[1]);x=m-1;d=x==1?(y%4==0?(y%100==0?(y%400==0?29:28):29):28):(x==3||x==5||x==10?30:31);if((d+=m<3?y--:y-2,23*m/9+d+4+y/4-y/100+y/400)%7==1)printf("%d\n",m);}}
```

## Compile

```
gcc -std=c99 -o foo foo.c
```

## Ungolfed

With credits to the relevant gurus.

*Michael Keith* and *Tom Craver* for [C Program to find day of week given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054016/c-program-to-find-day-of-week-given-date).

*Collin Biedenkapp* for [Q&A: How do I figure out what the last day of the month is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630821/qa-how-do-i-figure-out-what-the-last-day-of-the-month-is)

```
/* credit to Collin Biedenkapp */
short _get_max_day(short x, int z) {
    if(x == 0 || x == 2 || x == 4 || x == 6 || x == 7 || x == 9 || x == 11)
        return 31;
    else if(x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 8 || x == 10)
        return 30;
    else {
        if(z % 4 == 0) {
            if(z % 100 == 0) {
                if(z % 400 == 0)
                    return 29;
                return 28;
            }
            return 29;
        }
        return 28;
    }
}

main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
 for(int y,d,m=12;m;m--) {
  y=atoi(argv[1]);
  d=_get_max_day(m-1,y);
  /* credit to Michael Keith and Tom Craver */
  if ((d+=m<3?y--:y-2,23*m/9+d+4+y/4-y/100+y/400)%7 == 1)
    printf("%d\n",m);
 }
}
```

Comment: What if you flip your `if` the other direction, to have your `else` return `31`, and therefore you can eliminate the big `==` chain?

Comment: would be better if(x==1) {z part}else if(x==3|| x == 5 || x == 8 || x == 10)return 30 else return 31

Comment: what about: return  x==1?(z%4==0?(z%100==0?(z%400==0?29:28):29):28):(x==3||x==5||x==8||x==10?30:31)

Comment: TimmyD + RosLuP : thanks for the return() points, 100 bytes now saved.

Comment: it is possible continue to reduce at last until this: u(y,m){return m-1?30+((2773>>m)&1):28+(y%4==0&&y%100||y%400==0);} where y is the year and m the month

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 92 Bytes

```
for($d=new DateTime("$argv[1]-1-1");$i++<12;)$d->modify("1month")->format(w)!=2?:print"$i,";
```

check 12 times 1 month after first day of a year is a tuesday. If it is then is the day before the last day in the month is a monday.

Comment: You could use echo instead of print and save 1

Comment: @Octopus not inside the ternary Operator

Answer (score 2):

## Bash+cal, 58 bytes

```
$ cat t.sh
for A in {1..12};do cal $A $1|grep -qx .....&&echo $A;done
$ bash t.sh 2016
2
10
$
```

Comment: +1 - works for BSD `cal` (e.g. OSX), but watch for trailing spaces on GNU `cal`.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 54 + 6 = 60 bytes

```
λ cat monday.rb
p (1..12).select{|m|Date.new($*[0].to_i,m,-1).monday?}
λ ruby -rdate monday.rb 2016
[2, 10]
```

6 bytes for `-rdate` on the command line to get the Date class from the standard library.

Explanation: pretty straightforward thanks to the Ruby stdlib's great `Date` class. Not only does it have methods like `monday?`, `tuesday?`, etc, the constructor will take negative numbers for any field past year to mean 'count this field backwards from the end of the period represented by the previous field'. `$*` is shorthand for `ARGV`, so `$*[0]` is a quick way to get the first command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 94 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
lambda y:[m for m in range(1,13)if date(y+(m>11),m%12+1,1).weekday()==1]
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/EHX5/1)**

An unnamed function, takes an integer year, outputs a list of the month numbers `[1-12]`.

I also tried to beat the byte count with arithmetic without success (110 bytes). :

```python
lambda y:map(lambda x,v:(23*((x+2)%13or 1)/9+y-2*(0<x<11)+(x>10)+v/4-v/100+v/400)%7==4,range(12),[y-1]+[y]*11)
```

An unnamed function which returns a list of boolean values representing if the months [Jan-Dec] end in a Monday

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>200</s> 249 bytes

```
import java.util.*;String c(int y){String r="";GregorianCalendar c=new GregorianCalendar();c.setGregorianChange(new Date(1L<<63));c.set(1,y);c.set(2,0);for(int i=0;i++<12;c.add(2,1)){c.set(5,c.getActualMaximum(5));if(c.get(7)==2)r+=i+" ";}return r;}
```

In Java, `GregorianCalendar` is a mix between a Gregorian and Julian calendar. Because of this, year `1` gave incorrect results. Changing `Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();` to `GregorianCalendar c=new GregorianCalendar();c.setGregorianChange(new Date(1L<<63));` fixes this by forcing a use of the Gregorian calendar only. [Thanks to *@JonSkeet* on stackoverflow.com for explaining this to me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280182/calendar-giving-unexpected-results-for-year-1/40280292#40280292)

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/ZAwjCg)

```
import java.util.*;
class M{
  static String c(int year){
    String r = "";
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i++ < 12; calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)){
      calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
      if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 2){
        r += i+" ";
      }
    }
    return r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(1));
    System.out.println(c(297));
    System.out.println(c(1776));
    System.out.println(c(2000));
    System.out.println(c(2016));
    System.out.println(c(3385));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
4 12
5 
9 
1 7 
2 10 
1 2 10
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>106</s> <s>99</s> <s>95</s> <s>83</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```
g=function(x)which(format(seq(as.Date(paste0(x,-2,-1)),,'m',12)-1,"%u")<2)
```

The sequence of last days of each month is given by `seq(as.Date(paste0(x,-2,-1)),,'m',12)-1`:

- `paste0` coerces -2 and -1 to characters. If the `x` was 2016 for instance, `paste0(x,-2,-1)` gives `"2016-2-1"` which is then converted to the 1st of February 2016 by `as.Date`.
- `seq` applied to a POSIXct or a Date object is `seq(from, to , by, length.out)`: here `to` is not given, `by` is given as `'m'` which is matched to `'month'` thanks to partial matching, and `length.out` is of course 12.
- The resulting sequence is the first day of the 12 months starting with February of the year in question. `-1` gives us then the last day of the 12 months starting with January of the year in question.

Test cases:

```
> g(1)
[1]  4 12
> g(25)
[1] 3 6
> g(297)
[1] 5
> g(2000)
[1] 1 7
> g(2016)
[1]  2 10
> g(3385)
[1]  1  2 10
> g(9999)
[1] 5
```

**Old version at 95 bytes, outputting the month names instead of just their numbers:**

```
g=function(x)format(S<-seq(as.Date(sprintf("%04i-02-01",x)),,'m',12)-1,"%B")[format(S,"%u")==1]
```

Comment: This answer is just brilliant. I had no idea `seq` had a method for `Date` -objects and this solves the issue of `as.Date` not handling years above `10000` in my deleted answer.

Comment: @Billywob yes `seq.Date` and `seq.POSIXt` are quite impressive: they can even process commands such as `seq(time1, time2, by="10 min")` or `seq(date1, date2, by="quarter")`. Very useful when plotting a time-series.

Answer (score 2):

## <s>C#6</s> C#, <s>171</s> <s>167</s> 135 bytes

```
using System;
void d(int n){for(int i=0;++i<13;)if((int)new DateTime(n,i,DateTime.DaysInMonth(n,i)).DayOfWeek==1)Console.Write(i+" ");}
```

*-32 bytes thanks to Shebang*

Print months as numbers; with space delimited; with trailing space. Now this answer also works for earlier versions of C#.

---

Old, 167 bytes

```
using System;using System.Linq;
c(int n)=>string.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(1,12).Where(i=>new DateTime(n,i,DateTime.DaysInMonth(n,i)).DayOfWeek==(DayOfWeek)1));
```

*-4 bytes thanks to TimmyD*

Output months are numbers in return string, comma delimited

Ungolfed

```
string c(int n)=>
    string.Join(",",                                        // Join them with commas
        Enumerable.Range(1,12)                              // For 1-12 inclusive
        .Where(                                             // Select only
            i=>new DateTime(n,i,DateTime.DaysInMonth(n,i)   // Get last day of that year-month
            ).DayOfWeek                                     // Get its day of week
            ==(DayOfWeek)1                              // Is Monday
        )
    )
;
```

Comment: @TimmyD Yes but need explicit cast. Answer updated

Comment: LINQ is fun but this is 126 bytes: `void q(int y){for(int m=1;m<13;m++){if((int)new DateTime(y,m,DateTime.DaysInMonth(y,m)).DayOfWeek==1){Console.WriteLine(m);}}}` ;) Also, it would be shorter to cast the `DayOfWeek` to `int` than it would be to cast the `int` to `DayOfWeek`

Comment: @Shebang Thanks. I really shouldn't golf in one-line linq --- Only Jon Skeet can do that. See if I have time for update tomorrow. Tired now.

Comment: You can convert this to be an `Action<int>` to save some bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 24 bytes

```
Do1 £Ov"Ð400+U"+X e ¥2©X
```

[**Test it online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=RG8xIKNPdiLQNDAwK1UiK1ggZSClMqlY&input=MjAxNg==) Outputs an array of numbers, with `false` in place of months that don't end in a Monday.

There was a bug in the interpreter that didn't allow me to use `Ð` in the function body `£`. After the bug fix and another feature addition, this is 18 bytes in the current commit:

```
Do1@Ð400+UX e ¥2©X
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>143</s> 129 bytes

This uses the new time API of Java 8.

```
y->{String s="";for(int m=0;++m<13;)if(java.time.YearMonth.of(y,m).atEndOfMonth().getDayOfWeek().ordinal()==0)s+=m+" ";return s;}
```

### Output

Note that each line has an extra space at the end.

```
4 12 
5 
9 
1 7 
2 10 
1 2 10
```

### Ungolfed and testing

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        IntFunction<String> func = year -> {
          String result = "";
          for (int month=1; month <= 12; month++) {
            if (YearMonth.of(year, month).atEndOfMonth().getDayOfWeek().ordinal() == 0) {
              result += month + " ";
            }
          }
          return result;
        };
        System.out.println(func.apply(1));
        System.out.println(func.apply(297));
        System.out.println(func.apply(1776));
        System.out.println(func.apply(2000));
        System.out.println(func.apply(2016));
        System.out.println(func.apply(3385));
    }
}
```

### Shaves

1. 143 to 129 bytes: use `DayOfWeek::ordinal` to compare with a numerical constant instead of the enum constant.
   Thanks @TimmyD for the general idea if not the exact solution! ;-)

Comment: @TimmyD sadly, it's an enum. It does have a `getValue()` method, though, which would save a few bytes.

Comment: @Celos `ordinal()` saves 1 more byte compared to `getValue()`, even though it is suggested to never use it.

Comment: yes, good thinking. I posted my comment without first refreshing, so I didn't see your reply and edit.

Answer (score 1):

## GNU awk, 80 bytes

```
{for(;m<13;a=mktime($0" "++m" 1 9 0 0")){if(strftime("%w",a-8e4)~1){print m-1}}}
```

Example

```
$ gawk '{for(;m<13;a=mktime($0" "++m" 1 9 0 0")){if(strftime("%w",a-8e4)~1){print m-1}}}' <<<2016
2
10
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 109 bytes

```
$y=$argv[1];for($i;++$i<13;)echo(date('N',strtotime($y."-$i-".date('t',strtotime("$y-$i-1"))))==1?"$i ":'');
```

The code produces a notice due to `for($i;` but the question mentions nothing about avoiding errors.

---

Outputs months numbers separated by a space.

```
   1 --> 1 12 
 297 --> 5 
1776 --> 9 
2000 --> 1 7 
2016 --> 2 10 
3385 --> 1 2 10
```

---

Works in PHP 5.2.16 and onward at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: STDERR [is ignored by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/42963), so this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 65 bytes

```
v=>[...""+1e11].map((x,i)=>new Date(v+400,++i).getDay()==2?i:"")
```

Stealing the `""+1e11` trick from the other JavaScript answer.

Returns ["", 2, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 10, "", ""] for 2016, indicating that Feb and Oct end on a Monday.

Edited: Years 0-99 are parsed as 1900-1999 in JS.  Adding 400 causes them to be parsed as 400-499, which are equivalent calendar years.

Answer (score 1):

**C, <s>175</s> 217 bytes**

```
#define R return
#define L(i) for(;i-->0;) 
u(y,m){R m-1?30+((2773>>m)&1):28+(y%4==0&&y%100||y%400==0);}s(y,m,g){g+=4;L(m)g+=u(y,m),g%=7;L(y)g+=1+u(y,1),g%=7;R g;}w(y,m,r){m=12;L(m)s(y,m,u(y,m))||(r|=1<<(m+1));R r;}
```

Code for to find the last day for febrary taken from K&R2; try http://ideone.com/XtuhGj the function for debug is w

```
z(y,m,r){m=12;L(m)s(y,m,13)-4||(r|=1<<(m+1));R r;}

/*    
// ritorna il numero dei giorni di anno=y mese=m con mese in 0..11
// m==1 significa febbraio   y%4?0:y%100?1:!(y%400) non funziona
u(y,m){R m-1?30+((2773>>m)&1):28+(y%4==0&&y%100||y%400==0);}

// argomenti anno:y[0..0xFFFFFFF]  mese:m[0..11]  giorno:g[1..u(y,m)]
// ritorna il numero del giorno[0..6]
s(y,m,g)
{g+=4; // correzione per il giorno di partenza anno mese giorno = 0,1,1
 L(m)g+=  u(y,m),g%=7; // m:0..m-1  somma mod 7 i giorni del mese dell'anno y
 L(y)g+=1+u(y,1),g%=7; // y:0..y-1  somma mod 7 gli anni da 0..y-1
                       // g+=1+u(y,1) poiche' (365-28)%7=1 e 1 e' febbraio
 R g;
}

// argomenti anno:y[0..0xFFFFFFF], m=0 r=0 
// calcola tutti gli ultimi giorni del mese dell'anno y che cadono di lunedi'
// e mette tali mesi come bit, dal bit 1 al bit 12 [il bit 0 sempre 0] in r
w(y,m,r){m=12;L(m)s(y,m,u(y,m))||(r|=1<<(m+1));R r;}

// argomenti anno:y[0..0xFFFFFFF], m=0 r=0 
//ritorna in r il numero dei mesi che ha giorno 13 di venerdi[==4]
// e mette tali mesi come bit, dal bit 1 al bit 12 [il bit 0 sempre 0] in r
z(y,m,r){m=12;L(m)s(y,m,13)-4||(r|=1<<(m+1));R r;}
*/

#define P printf
#define W while 
#define M main 
#define F for
#define U unsigned
#define N int
#define B break
#define I if
#define J(a,b)  if(a)goto b
#define G goto
#define P printf
#define D double
#define C unsigned char
#define A getchar()
#define O putchar
#define Y malloc
#define Z free
#define S sizeof
#define T struct
#define E else
#define Q static
#define X continue
M()
{N y,m,g,r,arr[]={1,297,1776,2000,2016,3385}, arr1[]={2016,1,1997,1337,123456789};
 C*mese[]={"gen","feb","mar","apr","mag","giu","lug","ago","set","ott","nov","dic"};
 C*giorno[]={"Lun","Mar","Mer","Gio","Ven","Sab","Dom"};
 P("Inserisci Anno mese giorno>");r=scanf("%d %d %d", &y, &m, &g);
 P("Inseriti> %d %d %d r=%d\n", y, m, g, r);
 I(r!=3||m>12||m<=0||g>u(y,m-1))R 0;
 r=s(y,m-1,g);// 12-> 11 -> 0..10
 P("Risultato=%d giorno=%s\n", r, giorno[r]);
 r=w(y,0,0);P(" r=%d ", r);P("\n");
 F(m=0;m<6;++m)
        {P("N anno=%d -->",arr[m]); 
         r=w(arr[m],0,0); // ritorna in r i mesi tramite i suoi bit...
         F(y=1;y<13;++y) I(r&(1<<y))P("%s ",mese[y-1]);
         P("\n");
        }
 F(m=0;m<4;++m)
        {P("N anno=%d -->",arr1[m]); 
         r=z(arr1[m],0,0); // ritorna in r i mesi tramite i suoi bit...
         F(y=1;y<13;++y) I(r&(1<<y))P("%s ",mese[y-1]);
         P("\n");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>73</s> 65 bytes

```powershell
param($a)1..12|?{"$_/1/$a"|get-date|% *hs 1|% *ys -1|? d*k -eq 1}
```

This requires the regional settings to use the `en-US` date format.

### Explanations

Assumes the year is a `string` with padded zeros:

```powershell
param($a)                     # Declares an input variable
1..12                         # Creates a range for each month
 |?                           # Filters each month
  {"$_/1/$a"                  # Creates a date for the first of the month Month/Day/Year
   |get-date
   |% *hs 1                   # *hs calls AddMonths
   |% *ys -1                  # *hs calls AddDays, -1 goes to the last day of the previous month
   |? d*k -eq 1}              # d*k calls DayOfWeek, 1 is the int value for the DayOfWeek.Monday
```

Thanks to *mazzy* for the idea of piping parameters into `get-date`!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP2/ILEoMVdDJVHTUE/P0KjGvlpJJV7fUF8lUakmPbVENyWxJLVGVUEro1jBEERXFivoGtbYK6RoZSvophYqGNb@r@XiUgMapm5gYGCozqWkBOUZWZrDeYbm5mYwthFQHYJtCBc3NrYw/Q8A)

Comment: `[datetime]::new` is really shorter! Nice! +[a bit of CodeGolf](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP2/ILEoMVdDJVHTUE/P0KjGvjraJbEkNSQzNzXWyiovtRwopaMSr2OoWaOqoJVRrGAIoiuLFXQNa@wVUrSyFXRTCxUMa//XcnGpAY005FJSAjMUjCzNYWxDc3MzGNvIwMAAwTaEixsbW5j@BwA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##RczfCoIwHMXx@z3FQVaUMNlvUquL8FFi5EpImW1CiPPZ1x@wrs6Hc/Ht3dP60Ni2FRfnbeJXnDCl3njTbbjZUlGQitVE8WYHUZvBQozgBqJz4Oe4Qt4E0GfHAEGxQp3fIewDNKeZsfW7SCzLvoA66sWk9X6xklL@Tb@/LA@79AI "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") :)

Comment: thanks. the `"$_/1/$a"` works with the `en_us` region only. it does not work with german or russian regions.

Comment: Yes, I did it on purpose and had to adapt it to the Try it online culture.
Is it an ok approach? Or should use another solution?

Comment: I think it would be ok if you explicitly wrote about regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs an array of all months, where `0`s are months that don't end in Mondays and all other integers are the 1-based indices of the months.

```
CõÈ*=1¶ÐUXJ e
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Q/XIKj0xttBVWEogZQ&input=MjAwMA)

If run in a locale where Monday is the first day of the week, with 0-based indexing, we could save 2 bytes with:

```
CõÈ*!ÐUXJ e
```

Or push the loose output format a little further by returning an array of Booleans with:

```
Cõ@!ÐUXJ e
```

### Explanation

```
CõÈ*=1¶ÐUXJ e      :Implicit input of integer U
C                  :12
 õ                 :Range [1,C]
  È                :Map each X
   *=              :  Multiply by and reassign
     1¶            :  Test 1 for equality with
       Ð           :  Create date object using
        U          :    U for the year
         X         :    X for the 0-based month ([0,11]=[Jan,Dec] but [1,12]=[Feb,Jan])
          J        :    -1 for the date, wrapping us back to the last day of the previous month
            e      :  0-based index of the day of the week (0=Sunday)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 62 bytes

```
E,(;qiaf+{[~_2$3<_!-2*@@- 4/_25/_4/\W*](23*9/+:+7%4=}%ee::*0-`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31VHw7owMzFNuzq6Lt5IxdgmXlHXSMvBQVfBRD/eyFQ/3kQ/JlwrVsPIWMtSX9tK21zVxLZWNTXVykrLQDfh/38jA0MzAA)

Uses an algorithm adapted from [Mike Keith](http://cadaeic.net/calendar.htm). The program calculates the weekday of the first day of the next month, then checks if that day is a Tuesday. Output is a string representation of an array of month indices, e.g. `[2 10]`.

If output can be in the form of a binary array with 0 meaning false and 1 meaning true for each of the 12 months, you can get away with [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31XHyK4wMzFNuzq6Lt5IxdgmXlHXSMvBQVfBRD/eyFQ/3kQ/JlwrVsPIWMtSX9tK21zVxLZWNeH/fyMDQzMA).

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 92 bytes

Input parameter needs to be padded with zeros if the year is before 1000

```sql
SELECT number+1FROM spt_values
WHERE number<12and
datepart(w,eomonth(@,number))=2and'P'=type
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1321008/the-last-monday)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>141</s> 136 bytes

```java
y->{for(int i=0;++i<13)if(java.time.LocalDate.of(y,i,1).plusMonths(1).minusDays(1).getDayOfWeek().getValue()<2)System.out.println(i);};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY8xa8MwFIRn61dolEgi7HRUnKVZCg0dAu1QOqiO5DxHloz0FDDBv91VTLPdfRzcXaduatOdrzOBfvABaZeBSAhWmOQaBO/Eq3cx9TpIQob0a6GhjVUx0qMCR@@EFBEVZvrM7d4c6laHPTU1ndnIN/u78YGBQwp1JWFXvUhYrTgYttQh9Fq8@0bZg0ItvGHjGtYVF4NN8egdXiLLrgeX4kGNi2k1ZvlhvrS@ssV@Kps047stp6cxou6FTyiGkGutY8DlJMksnxf@N988nGmfj7AT5mT7/UNVaCPPv4riMXjUKtTbsixlBkaoptEDsgflmUzT/Ac)

To get the last day of each month I get the first day of the next month and substract 1 day. Java date function `getDayOfWeek()` returns the day of the week (Monday=1)

141 -> 136 : small improvements (thanks to @ceilingcat)

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 83 bytes

```
f={y->(1..12).findAll{sprintf('%ta',(java.time.YearMonth.of(y,it)+1<<1)-1)=='Mon'}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/zba6UtdOw1BPz9BIUy8tMy/FMSenurigKDOvJE1DXbUkUV1HIyuxLFGvJDM3VS8yNbHINz@vJEMvP02jUiezRFPb0MbGUFPXUNPWVh0oo15b@z@xuDi1qEQhTcNQU8HWViEaosExIMjTR0cBwnFxdXb1dXINitXSK0vMKU3lgusxsjRH1uXrGImpxtDUwogYRcbIirwc/UIdgyJhLnBzdQpC5vs7h/hjdZChubkZsjnBrgEhuNxuYGCAx0qvUJ9IbJoMUcwn2mHGxham5HvwPwA)

The return format is a List of 1-based months.

(Doesn't currently work in TIO since it is using the [`YearMonth.plus(long months)`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/time/YearMonth.html#plus(long)) method, which was added in Groovy 2.5.0.  TIO currently uses Groovy 2.4.8).

`sprintf('%ta',value)` returns the 3-letter month name.

`YearMonth.of(y,it)+1` returns the `YearMonth` after the given month; `YearMonth<<1` returns the `LocalDate` of the first of the month.  Subtracting 1 from this returns the last day of the previous month.  This is all just a convoluted way of returning `YearMonth.of(y,it).atEndOfMonth()` in 4 fewer characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```
f={y->(1..12).findAll{"${new Date(y+100,it,0)}"[0]=='M'}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/zba6UtdOw1BPz9BIUy8tMy/FMSenWkmlOi@1XMElsSRVo1Lb0MBAJ7NEx0CzVinaINbWVt1Xvbb2f2ZuQX5RiUJWYlmiXklmbqqeb35eSQZXYnFxKlA4TcNQU8HWViEaLKrnGBDk6aOjAOG4uDq7@jq5BsVq6ZUl5pSmIvQYWZoj6/J1jMRUY2hqYUSMImNkRV6OfqGOQZEwF7i5OgUh8/2dQ/yxOsjQ3NwM2Zxg14AQXG43MDDAY6VXqE8kNk2GKOYT7TBjYwtT8j34HwA)

The return format is a `List<Integer>` of 0-based months.

This uses the legacy `Date(int year, int month, int date)` constructor that takes a year (minus 1900), the 0-based month, and the day of month.

The legacy `Date` class uses the Julian calendar prior to 1583.  However, the day-of-week is on a 400 year cycle, so I added 2000 (400*5) to the date.  Since 1900 has to be subtracted from the input date, I'm actually passing in the three-character number 100 (2000-1900) for the year.

In order to get the last day of the month, I'm passing in months 1-12 (February through the following year's January, since `Date` uses 0-based months) and day-of-month 0 (the day before the first of that month).  This gets me the last day of January - December of the given year.

Finally, the string representation of `Date` is in "Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 CDT 2020" format.  I'm converting the date to a `GString` using string interpolation, and then comparing the first character of that string to "M" for "Monday".